# Do Baidu and/or Yandex publish the current IP ranges used by their site indexing bots?

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engines, ip-address

I need to identify bots operated by search engine operators to index sites.

I've looked at [an existing question on this matter](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31837/how-to-block-baidu-spiders) and the answers given there are too simplistic.

The `User-Agent` header is easy to fake, so checking it is not enough.
Their IP addresses need to be checked, too; but search engine operators don't work with fixed ranges of IP addresses these days.

IP addresses can be checked with reverse DNS lookup, but DNS lookups can be slow.

It would be much faster to check against a list of IP ranges for bots published by the search engine operator:

- Write a script to

  - fetch the list
  - convert it into a bunch of IP-based access rules for the web server
  - reload the web server to activate them
- Schedule the script to run, say, once every night.

At the expense of sometimes being slightly inaccurate, this eliminates the need for a reverse DNS lookup on each request.

Google and Bing publish such lists.

Does Baidu? [Their documentation](https://help.baidu.com/question?prod_id=99&class=0&id=3001) doesn't mention it.

Does Yandex? [Their documentation](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/robot-workings/check-yandex-robots.html) doesn't mention it, either.

If they don't, is there any other reliable way to get these lists?

Comment: Reverse DNS can be slow, but it is a viable solution when used with caching.

Comment: That's what I ended up implementing, but I'd still like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: FWIW reverse DNS can be faked, I mean anyone owning any IP can decide to publish a reverse record on any arbitrary name. Totally useless, except to hide, but otherwise trivial. The only check would be to do "reverse query then forward query" and see if it matches (but there would be ton of false negatives too as both trees are separate in the DNS and not always in sync). The other options is to look at RIR databases and try to find out which IP blocks the company own, but that will also yields lots of false negatives and positives.